# how to replace label text with text in the column c#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, select, sql-server-ce

I am trying to enter a studentID in a windows form text box and I want the corresponding label to change text from label1 to the data from the name column. I am really confused with the code, therefore the following.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {


                    SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|datadirectory|databse.sdf");
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCeCommand cmdSelect = conn.CreateCommand();
                    cmdSelect.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM StudentDetails WHERE StudentID = studentIDTextBox.Text";

                    SqlCeDataReader sr = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader();
                    DataSet sd = new DataSet();



                }
                  /* using (SqlCeDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM StudentDetails WHERE StudentID = '" + studentIDTextBox.Text.ToString() + "'", conn)
                    {

                        // create the DataSet 
                        DataSet ITIADataSet = new DataSet();
                        // fill the DataSet using our DataAdapter 
                        dataAdapter.Fill();


        }
    }
    */
```

Comment: I guess you are using Winforms?

Comment: Yes I am using informs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first thing's first - your SQL code won't find anything because its looking for the string "studentIDTextBox.Text"

You want " + studentIDTextBox.Text

Secondly, directly putting strings into SQL code is a really good way of leaving yourself open to an SQL injection attack.

Otherwise, you're almost there.

I'd go for something like this:

```
string studentName = string.Empty;
    while (sr.Read())
    {
     studentName = sr["StudentName"].toString();

    }

lblMyLabel.Text = studentName;
```

Of course you need to handle for when you return no data.

And don't forget to close the connection when you're done with it.

Comment: It worked for me, but the thing is that I have multiple labels on the form and I want to get data from my table and replace the text on all the labels, so would dataset be helpful?

Comment: If you want to replace the text of the labels from one result from the database. You could follow the example above and say lblMyLabel.Text = sr["MyColumnName'].ToString();

Comment: yes, I did that. Thnx a lot :) but was just wondering on how to use dataset in this program.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `studentIDTextBox.Text` in a query like that. It will be treated as text. The best way is to use a parameterized query

```
cmdSelect.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM StudentDetails WHERE StudentID = @StudentID";
cmdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID",studentIDTextBox.Text);
or
cmdSelect.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@StudentID",SqlDbType.{YourColumnDataType}){Value = studentIDTextBox.Text}
```

OR a quick fix

```
cmdSelect.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT * FROM StudentDetails WHERE StudentID = {0}",studentIDTextBox.Text);
```

Note the above is vulnerable to an SQL Injection Attack

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this:

```
cmdSelect.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM StudentDetails WHERE StudentID = studentIDTextBox.Text";
```

As that will not put in the value. You'd want something like this.

`cmdSelect.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM StudentDetails WHERE StudentID = " + studentIDTextBox.Text;`

Comment: This is very vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: Indeed. I wouldn't personally put SQL in code like this ever. Prefer to use stored procedures every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|datadirectory|databse.sdf");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter("select MyDesiredValue from StudentDetails where StudentID = " + studentIDTextBox.Text + "", conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            label1.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
```